# VPN only user cannot cancel virtual server

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have a VPN only user. I utilize for automation via slcli. I can order virtual servers successfully, but cannot cancel the virtual server I ordered. I get

```
$ slcli virtual cancel 29509049
```

Exception:

> This action cannot be undone! Type "29509049" or press Enter to abort:
>   29509049 SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): This
>   cancellation could not be processed please contact support.This
>   cancellation could not be processed. Please contact support. Unable to
>   create cancel ticket for virtual server.

I check the user permissions and I have:

- SERVER_ADD
- SERVER_CANCEL
- TICKET_ADD
- VIRTUAL_GUEST_VIEW

Is there some other permission I need? What else could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To cancel Virtual Servers, you need the following permissions:

> - SERVER_CANCEL
> - TICKET_VIEW
> - VIRTUAL_GUEST_VIEW
> - TICKET_ADD
> - TICKET_EDIT

So, you need to add these permissions: **TICKET_VIEW** and **TICKET_EDIT**

Comment: Thanks -- `TICKET_EDIT` was the missing permission. Who would have guessed